# Json.Stringfy replace method with function to array

Tags: javascript, json

I am still learning javascript and recently I stumbled upon this piece of code on the internet explaining the JSON.stringify replace with an array:

```
var ar = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function replacer2(i, val) {
    if ( i === '0' ) { // identity operator and index in quotes
        return undefined; // attempt to remove from result
    } else if ( i == 1 ) { // equality operator and numeric version of index
        return 2;
    } else {
        return val; // return unchanged
    }
}

var json = JSON.stringify(ar, replacer2);
console.log(json);
// [null,2,"three"]
```

source:https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/filter.php
Now the part that I don't get is the function parameters of replacer 2 which is i and val. I get that i is supposed to be the index and val is ar(correct me if I'm wrong here). But how is the function able to know that? How is it able to differentiate the index and the value of ar?

Comment: That's the replacer, "it takes two parameters: the key and the value being stringified." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Function `replacer2` knows nothing. It is just get parameters (i, val) with help of calling by JSON.stringify (assumed as [JSON.stringify replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#replacer) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `index` and `value`

First of all understand this `Array is also an object`. With keys 0,1,2.... which we assumes as index.

And in your function two parameters are `key` and `value` of object. If you do `JSON.stringify` on following object

```
{
   foo: 'a',
   bar: 'b'
}
```

You will get parameters as `'foo', 'a'` in first iteration and `'bar', 'b'` in second iteration.

Hope I am clear.